# How can I show an image of Recommendation records that are generated from Recommendation Builder on Next Best Action component?

Tags: einstein, einstein-recommendations, einstein-next-best-action

My problem is just described as a title.
I am struggling to show an image of each recommendations. I know it is able to display an image if it is not used `Einstein Load` node on Strategy Builder.

The image on recommendation should be used `ImageId` field on recommendation object, so I created an enhanced apex class to add each `ImageId` with `ContentAssetId` but still no luck.

[image]

Any advises would be appreciated.